# rosserial_arduino error

Tags: arduino, macos, rosserial, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using OSX 10.7.3 with Arduino IDE 1.0

When I followed the [directions](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup) to install rosserial from source, I did: hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg rosserial. Everything compiled and I copied the ros_lib folder to my Arduino/Library folder. However when I try to compile any of the included example program (e.g., Hello World), it fails with the following error:

```
  In file included from /Users/kevin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:39,
             from HelloWorld.cpp:6:
  /Users/kevin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h:38:22: error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory
  In file included from /Users/kevin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:39,
             from HelloWorld.cpp:6:
  /Users/kevin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h: In member function 'long unsigned int ArduinoHardware::time()':
  /Users/kevin/Documents/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h:73: error: 'millis' was not declared in this scope
```

A quick look at the [release notes](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ReleaseNotes) for Arduino says:

---

The WProgram.h file, which provides declarations for the Arduino API,
has been renamed to Arduino.h. To create a library that will work in
both Arduino 0022 and Arduino 1.0, you can use an #ifdef that checks
for the ARDUINO constant, which was 22 and is now 100.  For example:

```
 #if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
 #include "Arduino.h"
 #else
 #include "WProgram.h"
 #endif
```

---

Am I grabbing out dated code from the wrong CVS??? This change to Arduino was made a while ago, so I don't understand how I am the first to find it. Thanks!

---

**[UPDATE 1]**

I loaded the "hello world" sketch onto my Arduino, but now it crashes with :

```
[kevin@TARDIS ~]$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/cu.usbserial-A4001lNd
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 40, in <module>
from rosserial_python import SerialClient
File "/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from SerialClient import *
File "/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 42, in <module>
from serial import *
ImportError: No module named serial
```

Am I missing a dependency?

**[UPDATE 2]**

I figured out I needed to do:

```
pip install pyserial
```

But now it fails with:

```
[kevin@TARDIS rosserial]$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py  /dev/cu.usbserial-A4001lNd
[INFO] [WallTime: 1330658506.244201] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1330658506.251605] Connected on /dev/cu.usbserial-A4001lNd at 57600 baud
[INFO] [WallTime: 1330658508.750410] Note: publish buffer size is 280 bytes
[INFO] [WallTime: 1330658508.750905] Setup publisher on chatter [std_msgs/String]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1330658512.739698] Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data
[INFO] [WallTime: 1330658517.747113] Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data
[INFO] [WallTime: 1330658519.745485] Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data
[INFO] [WallTime: 1330658526.749475] Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data
[INFO] [WallTime: 1330658529.758370] Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py", line 58, in <module>
    client.run()
  File "/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 280, in run
    checksum = sum(map(ord,header) ) + sum(map(ord, msg)) + ord(chk)
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

So what is this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28749/rosserial_arduino-error/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We've been aware that this needs to change in rosserial for a while; see https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/trac/ticket/49 and apply the patch there.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2012-03-05**:
You might also note that our last rosserial release was more than a month before Arduino 1.0 came out. Arduino has dozens of developers, rosserial does not. Code sprints occur occasionally, but there is no full time maintainer of rosserial.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-06**:
@fergs If rosserial is only lightly maintained, could it be moved to a repository host that supports forking and pull requests like github or bitbucket?

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2012-12-06**:
To get the HelloWorld and String examples to compile under 1.0.2   convert 'char' to 'unsigned char'